# WSO2 DAS 3.0.1 proxy server configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

How can I configure the WSO2 DAS 3.0.1 to get through Proxy server in organization because it cannot download Google library when starting?

Cheers,
Sean

Comment: are you referring to a revers proxy such as nginx

Comment: first we need to update the conf.d within nginx by updating the upstream and server details where we configured the proxy pass and server details giving the host names as relevant. Also we need to Create SSL certificates for all nodes using the instructions given on  https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+NGINX

Comment: If Adding a custom proxy path is required when you have a proxy server fronting your Carbon server,the "custom proxy path" is used for mapping a proxy url with the actual url of your Carbon server, which allows clients to access the Carbon server with the proxy url. 
To configure the product with proxy context path within the  <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/ we need to update the <HostName> and the <MgtHostName> and set the <ProxyContextPath> as required. More details are available on  https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN447/Adding+a+Custom+Proxy+Path

Comment: BTW, will this cause wso2 das to fail? I cannot make das work with other issues along with the issue you mentioned here. Just wondering will DAS still work with this kind of errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass below properties as JVM options when starting the server to configure the proxy settings.

```
./wso2server.sh -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.100.1.100 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8088 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.0.0.1"
```

Alternatively you can append those parameters to the existing JVM options in the wso2server.sh.

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=10.100.1.100 \
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8088 \
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.0.0.1" \
```